# how to overlay two trips in static google map?

Tags: google-maps, static, overlay

I draw overlay for a trip from  one position to another using following url:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&sensor=false

i want to add another trip, so it shows two trips A to B and B to C.
i need to add more trips...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[map link](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.970318|40.749825,-73.987963&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aA|40.737102,-73.990318|&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aB|40.749825,-73.987963&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aC|40.737102,-73.970318&sensor=false)

right now you have 1 path parameter. To add another path simply add another path parameter to your url.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.970318|40.749825,-73.987963&markers=color:blue|label:A|40.737102,-73.990318|&markers=color:blue|label:B|40.749825,-73.987963&markers=color:blue|label:C|40.737102,-73.970318&sensor=false
```